# Alternating Series Test for Convergence - can the sequence be initially non-decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was given the following question:

> Determine if the following series is convergent. You may use basic
>   series, but you should clearly state which results or rules you use.
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n}}{n+4}$$

Does the Alternating Series Test require the positive term $\frac{\sqrt n}{n+4}$ to be decreasing for all $n$ or is it sufficient that the term is *eventually* decreasing? ($\frac{\sqrt n}{n+4}$ is decreasing only for $n>3$.)

Comment: Eventually decreasing is sufficient. This follows from the fact that convergence of a series is not affected by its first few terms.

Comment: Think about Riemann criterion.

Comment: @Monoide Why should they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you considering the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n{\sqrt n\over n+4}$?

In the criteria for the Alternating Series Test, the positive terms being eventually decreasing to 0 is sufficient for convergence of the series. This follows from the fact that convergence of a series is not affected by its first few terms.

So,  you could argue that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n{\sqrt n\over n+4}$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty (-1)^n{\sqrt n\over n+4}$ converges. The latter series converges by the Alternating Series Test; thus the former series converges.

Comment: Oh yes, of course-- the convergence of a series is not affected by altering a finite number of its terms. Thank you for clearing that up!